# How to plot columns from a dataframe as subplots

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, seaborn

What am I doing wrong here? I want to create for new dataframe from `df` and use Dates as the x-axis in a line chart for each newly created dataframe (Emins, FTSE, Stoxx and Nikkei).

I have a dataframe called `df` that I created from data.xlsx and it looks like this:

```
    Dates         ES1     Z 1     VG1     NK1
0   2005-01-04  -0.0126  0.0077 -0.0030  0.0052
1   2005-01-05  -0.0065 -0.0057  0.0007 -0.0095
2   2005-01-06   0.0042  0.0017  0.0051  0.0044
3   2005-01-07  -0.0017  0.0061  0.0010 -0.0009
4   2005-01-11  -0.0065 -0.0040 -0.0147  0.0070
3670    2020-09-16  -0.0046 -0.0065 -0.0003 -0.0009
3671    2020-09-17  -0.0083 -0.0034 -0.0039 -0.0086
3672    2020-09-18  -0.0024 -0.0009 -0.0009  0.0052
3673    2020-09-23  -0.0206  0.0102  0.0022 -0.0013
3674    2020-09-24  0.0021  -0.0136 -0.0073 -0.0116
```

From `df` I created 4 new dataframes called Eminis, FTSE, Stoxx and Nikkei.

Thanks for your help!!!!

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('classic')
    
    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    df = df.rename(columns={'Dates':'Date','ES1': 'Eminis', 'Z 1': 'FTSE','VG1': 'Stoxx','NK1': 'Nikkei','TY1': 'Notes','G 1': 'Gilts', 'RX1': 'Bunds','JB1': 'JGBS','CL1': 'Oil','HG1': 'Copper','S 1': 'Soybeans','GC1': 'Gold','WILLTIPS': 'TIPS'})
    headers = df.columns
    Eminis = df[['Date','Eminis']]
    FTSE = df[['Date','FTSE']]
    Stoxx = df[['Date','Stoxx']]
    Nikkei = df[['Date','Nikkei']]
    
    # create multiple plots via plt.subplots(rows,columns)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20,15))
    x = Date
    y1 = Eminis
    y2 = Notes
    y3 = Stoxx
    y4 = Nikkei
    
    # one plot on each subplot
    axes[0][0].line(x,y1)
    axes[0][1].line(x,y2)
    axes[1][0].line(x,y3)
    axes[1][1].line(x,y4)
    
    plt.legends()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As elegant solution is to:

- Set *Dates* column in your DataFrame as the index.
- Create a figure with the required number of subplots
  (in your case 4), calling *plt.subplots*.
- Draw a plot from your DataFrame, passing:

  - *ax* - the *ax* result from *subplots* (here it is an **array** of *Axes*
    objects, not a single *Axes*),
  - *subplots=True* - to draw each column in a separate
    subplot.

The code to do it is:

```
fig, a = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 6), tight_layout=True)
df.plot(ax=a, subplots=True, rot=60);
```

To test the above code I created the following DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(1)
ind = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2006-12-31', freq='7D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(ind.size, 4),
    index=ind, columns=['ES1', 'Z 1', 'VG1', 'NK1'])
```

and got the following picture:

[image]

As my test data are random, I assumed "7 days" frequency, to
have the picture not much "cluttered".
In the case of your real data, consider e.g. resampling with
e.g. also '7D' frequency and *mean()* aggregation function.

Answer (score 2):

- I think the more succinct option is not to make many dataframes, which creates unnecessary work, and complexity.
- Plotting data is about shaping the dataframe for the plot API
- In this case, a better option is to convert the dataframe to a long (tidy) format, from a wide format, using [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

  - This places all the labels in one column, and the values in another column
- Use [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot), which can create a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) from a dataframe in a long format.

  - `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`, and makes plotting much easier.
- If the dataframe contains many stocks, but only a few are to be plotted, they can be selected with [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import data from excel, or setup test dataframe
data = {'Dates': ['2005-01-04', '2005-01-05', '2005-01-06', '2005-01-07', '2005-01-11', '2020-09-16', '2020-09-17', '2020-09-18', '2020-09-23', '2020-09-24'],
        'ES1': [-0.0126, -0.0065, 0.0042, -0.0017, -0.0065, -0.0046, -0.0083, -0.0024, -0.0206, 0.0021],
        'Z 1': [0.0077, -0.0057, 0.0017, 0.0061, -0.004, -0.0065, -0.0034, -0.0009, 0.0102, -0.0136],
        'VG1': [-0.003, 0.0007, 0.0051, 0.001, -0.0147, -0.0003, -0.0039, -0.0009, 0.0022, -0.0073],
        'NK1': [0.0052, -0.0095, 0.0044, -0.0009, 0.007, -0.0009, -0.0086, 0.0052, -0.0013, -0.0116]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# cleanup the column names
df = df.rename(columns={'Dates': 'Date', 'ES1': 'Eminis', 'Z 1': 'FTSE', 'VG1': 'Stoxx','NK1': 'Nikkei'})

# set Date to a datetime
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# convert from wide to long format
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Stock', value_name='val')

# to select only a subset of values from Stock, to plot, select them with Boolean indexing
df_select = dfm[dfm.Stock.isin(['Eminis', 'FTSE', 'Stoxx', 'Nikkei'])]`

# df_select.head()
        Date   Stock     val
0 2005-01-04  Eminis -0.0126
1 2005-01-04    FTSE  0.0077
2 2005-01-04   Stoxx -0.0030
3 2005-01-04  Nikkei  0.0052
4 2005-01-05  Eminis -0.0065

# plot
g = sns.relplot(data=df_select, x='Date', y='val', col='Stock', col_wrap=2, kind='line')
```

[image]

### *What am I doing wrong here?*

- The current implementation is inefficient, has a number of incorrect method calls, and undefined variables.

  - `Date` is not defined for `x = Date`
  - `y2 = Notes`: `Notes` is not defined
  - `.line` is not a `plt` method and causes an `AttributeError`; it should be `plt.plot`
  - `y1 - y4` are DataFrames, but passed to the plot method for the y-axis, which causes `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`; one column should be passes as `y`.
  - `.legends` is not a method; it's `.legend`

    - The legend must be shown for each subplot, if one is desired.

```py
Eminis = df[['Date','Eminis']]
FTSE = df[['Date','FTSE']]
Stoxx = df[['Date','Stoxx']]
Nikkei = df[['Date','Nikkei']]

# create multiple plots via plt.subplots(rows,columns)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20,15))
x = df.Date
y1 = Eminis.Eminis
y2 = FTSE.FTSE
y3 = Stoxx.Stoxx
y4 = Nikkei.Nikkei

# one plot on each subplot
axes[0][0].plot(x,y1, label='Eminis')
axes[0][0].legend()
axes[0][1].plot(x,y2, label='FTSE')
axes[0][1].legend()
axes[1][0].plot(x,y3, label='Stoxx')
axes[1][0].legend()
axes[1][1].plot(x,y4, label='Nikkei')
axes[1][1].legend()

plt.show()
```